# How can I get all foreground applications?

Tags: android, foreground-service

Goal: I want to get all **foreground applications** that using `setForeground()` method that make a foreground notification.

Other questions are focusing at finding user interacting single application. But what I want is that finding all applications that are using services with `setForeground()` method.

Comment: we dont really tell you how to do something. its your job to start coding and when you get stuck, come here for help.

Comment: there is a hogh possibility that no 3rd-party apps can get such a list of applications bercause of security reasons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by using adb.

```
adb shell service list
```

This command returns all services in android. using `setForeground()` and this command, we got all foregrounded applications